# Using S3 error document with https

Tags: amazon-s3

We have an S3 bucket with website hosting enabled, and an error document set. We want to use it to serve images over https.

Over http, the 404 works fine: [example](http://upi-ir-posters.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/nothing.jpg). But for https, we need to use a different URL scheme, and the 404 no longer works: [example](https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/upi-ir-posters/nothing.jpg). (That URL scheme also fails with http: [example](http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/upi-ir-posters/nothing.jpg).)

Is there some way to do this? Have I misconfigured the S3 bucket, or something along those lines? (I've given 'list' permission to everyone, which turned the failure from a 403 to a 404, but not the 404 I want.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved this by setting up a Cloudfront as an interface to the S3 bucket.

One tricky bit: the origin for the CloudFront distribution needs to have origin protocol policy set to HTTP only. That means it can't directly be an S3 bucket, which always has 'match viewer' policy. Instead you can set it to the URL of an S3 bucket. Instead of BUCKET.s3.amazonaws.com, use the endpoint given by S3's static website hosting: BUCKET.s3-website-REGION.amazonaws.com.

This might have unintended side effects, and there might be better ways to do it, but it works.